# How create a grouped structure based off of a field in a query result?

Tags: cakephp, orm, query-builder, cakephp-3.1

I am trying to group by Year in cakephp3. I am able to get data using 
following way, but it's not still grouped by year(The way I want.)

```
$query = $this->Alerts->query();
$year = $query->func()->year([
    'added_on' => 'literal'
]);

$month = $query->func()->monthname(['added_on' => 'literal']);
$monthAlertsCount = $query->func()->count($month);
$data = $query
    ->select([
        'year' => $year,
        'month' => $month,
        'count' => $monthAlertsCount
    ])
    ->group($year)
    ->group($month);

$status = "success";
$this->set('response', $status);
$this->set('year', $data);
$this->set('_serialize', ['response','year']);
```

Current output is as follows:

```
{

    "response":"success",
    "year":[
        {
            "year":"2013",
            "month":"November",
            "count":"1"
        },
        {
            "year":"2014",
            "month":"February",
            "count":"2"
        },
        {
            "year":"2014",
            "month":"January",
            "count":"3"
        },
        {
            "year":"2015",
            "month":"December",
            "count":"6"
        },
        {
            "year":"2015",
            "month":"February",
            "count":"3"
        },
        {
            "year":"2015",
            "month":"January",
            "count":"4"
        },
        {
            "year":"2016",
            "month":"January",
            "count":"83"
        }
    ]

}
```

Expected Output:

```
{

    "response":"success",
    "year":[
        {
            "2013":[
                {
                    "month":"November",
                    "count":"1"
                }
            ],
            "2014":[
                {
                    "month":"February",
                    "count":"2"
                },
                {
                    "month":"January",
                    "count":"3"
                }
            ],
            "2015":[
                {
                    "month":"December",
                    "count":"6"
                },
                {
                    "month":"February",
                    "count":"3"
                },
                {
                    "month":"January",
                    "count":"4"
                }
            ],
            "2016":[
                {
                    "month":"January",
                    "count":"83"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

}
```

Can anybody help me get the expected output in cakephp3?

Answer (score 0):

Use the collection method `groupBy()` - remember, queries are collection objects (kind of)!

```
$data = $query
    ->select([
        'year' => $year,
        'month' => $month,
        'count' => $monthAlertsCount
    ])
    ->group($year)
    ->group($month)
    ->groupBy('year');
```

That will create the desired grouped structure, however it won't remove the `year` field from the individual rows, if you want them removed, use a mapper, like

```
// ...
->groupBy('year')
->map(function ($rows) {
    foreach ($rows as &$row) {
        unset($row['year']);
    }
    return $rows;
});
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Collections > Collection::groupBy()](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake%5CCollection%5CCollection::groupBy)**
- **[Cookbook > Collections > Collection::map()](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake%5CCollection%5CCollection::map)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Queries Are Collection Objects](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#queries-are-collection-objects)**

Comment: Hii, Thanks for your reply, it almost close to what i wanted, but I am not still able to remove year 

 ->groupBy('year')
->map(function ($row) {
    unset($row['year']);
    return $row;
});

does not remove year from the output

Comment: @AkshayMalhotra Forgot that the mapper doesn't traverse into the groups... check the updated code example.